# Is it considered blackhat SEO to have hidden text within links?

Tags: seo, links, blackhat, hidden-text

My aim is to simply be informative about where a link is pointing to search engines. I have some content that is listed by name and then I have a "Permalink" button. Would it be blackhat SEO to add some hidden text within the anchor that describes where the permalink is pointing?

My content is like so:

```
News Item 1
Permalink 
(<a href="/my-news-item-1"><hidden>News Item 1</hidden> Permalink</a>)
Teaser text..
```

The news title of the block already links to the article, but I think it would be of benefit to users to provide and explicit permalink button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd prefer to do a `<a href="" title="whichever the text"></a>`

Anyway, that seems to be a premade Dokuwiki tag? Which actually adds a javascript that initially sets a display:none to the block. If is the case I think it would not harm SEO.

Comment: After thinking it over, I think using title is actually the better road to go down.

Answer (score 3):

That is the very definition of black hat SEO. You are serving up different content to the search engines for the explicit purpose of manipulating their rankings.

The solution offered by S.gfx is the correct one. Additionally, search engines know that permalink is for that page. There's no need to stuff keywords in there. It won't make a difference anyway.

Comment: Good point, it's not worth risking blacklisting for something that probably wont effect rankings at all. +1